# Impressionist gem error: aggregates must have exactly one argument (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, impressionist

I have error in my app:

*SQLite3::SQLException: DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT ) FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = ? AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = ?.*

What Can I do?

**My model** product.rb has:

```
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :viewed_count, :uniq => true
```

**My controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  impressionist actions: [:show]

  def show
    ...
    impressionist(@product, nil, { unique: [:session_hash]})
  end

end
```

**My view** has:

```
= @product.impressionist_count(:filter=>:ip_address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues/355) which causes similar [issue in impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/178)? Please check your gem versions to be up to date.

Comment: I have checked. I use: gem 'impressionist', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1' and gem 'squeel', github: 'activerecord-hackery/squeel'.

Comment: The fix is still not merged to original repo, but you can try to install from godfat's one: `gem 'impressionist', github: 'godfat/impressionist', branch: 'compatible-with-squeel'`